# separate single row independent into columns in grid layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to create a grid layout where a single row is separated independently into columns like the following:

[image: expected output]

Here is the code I tried so far:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 300px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 127, 39);
}

.container::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 127, 39);
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

`.container::before` was just to show you separation of rows.

I know that I can use a little trick by inserting a fit `div` inside the first row of `container` and divide it into columns like the following:

[image: trick]

Since there are a lot of grid properties I don't know what they are used for, I would like to know what is the easiest way to do this.

Comment: What are you using for your grid layout - Bootstrap? Custom CSS? CSS Grid layout? Without seeing the css you are trying to use to do this, we can't help you fix the problem you are having with it.

Comment: it is not Bootstrap is CSS Grid layout I think now it is clear

Comment: OK, so where are the CSS Grid classes in your code? As I said, without seeing the CSS you are using, we can't help fix problems with it.

Comment: Do you want the first row to have a separate `grid-column` property from the second row?

Comment: exactly that's what I want

Comment: What column layout do you want for the second row?

Comment: 4 `columns` on the first row and 1 `column` on the second

Comment: Can you make the entire grid 4 columns, and set the last child of the grid to span column 1-4?

Comment: can you show me how ? please

Comment: `.container > *:last-child { grid-column: 1 / -1 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 300px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: .5rem;
}

.container> :last-child {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.container>div {
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```